# Micrometer spring legacy does not work in springboot 1.4.7 with ClassNotFound issue

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am currently configure a springboot 1.4.7 service to instrument metrics to prometheus.

Once I added the maven dependency micrometer-spring-legacy to pom.xml. I am unable to start the application. There are some ClassNotFound issue.

Have anyone see the same issue.

Many thanks

Comment: 1.4.7 is very old and it is not supported anymore.
Also, including the stacktrace in your question might help. :)

Comment: Why Spring boot 1.4.7 (released JUNE 08, 2017)? Try with the latest version.

Comment: @Habil this is the old project I inherited from. A lot of dependencies locked in Spring 1.4.7, risky to change to 2.0.0+ :(